# Composition of linear transform and nonlinear transform is nonlinear?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $g$ is nonlinear and $T$ is linear, then $T \circ g$ is necessarily nonlinear? We exclude the case where $T=0$.

Shame on me, I think this should be easy but I'm quite stuck. If $T$ is full-rank, then it is quite obvious, but otherwise, I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider for example $g: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2: (z_1,z_2) \mapsto (z_1,z_2^2)$, which is clearly non-linear. But $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2: (z_1,z_2) \mapsto (z_1,0)$ which is linear. And $T \circ g = T$, which is of course linear too.